# how to disable checkbox on confirm popup of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Hi everyone I need your help.

Generally, we have to get confirmation from the user before start process. In my issue, I open confirm box successfully but browser put a checkbox on confirm box. You know this I try to translate English this checkbox message. "Prevent to this site will create this message". I'll share screenshot of this popup. Now if the user check(He is user he does everything) this checkbox process couldn't work, it's wrong. Now I want to prevent this checkbox. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please don't. it is a browser feature.

Comment: You cant prevent this, its a browser feature. You are going to have to get your confirmation in a different way. Maybe a modal?

Comment: if your page is popping up so many messages that the browser displays this message, then probably your page needs a different design. This is a feature designed to stop spam and advertising popups, and also to stop the user getting infinite popups from badly programmed pages

Comment: @Milind Anantwar I know it is a browser feature I ask because may be we have some way prevent this. But I got it from yours comments don't. Ok. Thank you, we have to create own confirm modal.

Comment: @luffy: much better :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes much better but hard thing is how to give my confirm modal to kendo grid? And I've to write once but use everywhere. I have to study on this :)

Comment: @luffy: will take some time but worth doing than what you were trying to do...